# Merge - Mapping with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

I'm facing an issue with casting in AutoMapper. Following are details.

Here is my source class

```
public class FamilyModel
{
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my destination class

```
public class SaveKitViewModel
{
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i'm trying to caste source object to  destination object using Automapper it gives me error and I'm trying to ignore UserId object coz it's not present in Source class

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<FamilyModel, SaveKitViewModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.UserId, m => m.Ignore());
    }).CreateMapper();
   dbObject = mapper.Map(model, dbObject);
}
```

Can any one please tell me what's wrong with above code?

Comment: I'm getting following error @JamesDev

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UserId` isn't in the source map, you don't need to explicitly `.Ignore` it in the mapping bootstrapping - it will be ignored by default.

Seemingly you want to merge the mapped source properties into an existing destination object. You won't need to reassign the destination object - the existing properties will be mutated. For example:

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<FamilyModel, SaveKitViewModel>();
}).CreateMapper();

var existingSaveKitViewModel = new SaveKitViewModel
{
    UserId = 1234
};
var familyModel = new FamilyModel
{
    FamilyID = 9876,
    FamilyName = "Bloggs"
};
mapper.Map(familyModel, existingSaveKitViewModel);
```

Results in a merged `existingSaveKitViewModel`:

```
    FamilyID = 9876,
    FamilyName = "Bloggs"
    UserId = 1234
```

Comment: @HetalJariwala My example works as listed above - I've added it to [GitHub here](https://github.com/nonnb/SO36353982/blob/master/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs). Perhaps your MVCE isn't a true representation of the issue. Please edit your original question with the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
   cfg.CreateMap<FamilyModel, SaveKitViewModel>();
});

SaveKitViewModel sktv = new SaveKitViewModel();
FamilyModel fm = Mapper.Map<FamilyModel>(sktv.OfType<SaveKitViewModel>());
```